# Why TypeScript is not showing the error in browser?

Tags: typescript

I have this. Intentionally wrong so I can start learning Typescript.
Shouldn't it show me some error in the console?
I know at least it is getting into this function because it still prints the **Hello World** part.

```
function printFirstNames(friends) {

    console.log("Hello World!");

    for(let f of friends){
        console.log(f.firstName);
    }

}
printFirstNames(7);
//# sourceMappingURL=main.js.map
```

[image]

Comment: browsers run javascript, typescript transpiles to javascript.  The browser knows nothing about your original typescript. But your browser should be giving some kind of error about friends not being iterable since you're attempting to iterate a number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript compiles to JavaScript. And JavaScript is what is executed by the browser.

If you try to execute the following JS code in the browser:

```
for (let f of 7) {
    console.log(f.firstName);
}
```

You **will** get an error, telling you that 7 is not iterable.

So why don't you get that error when using TypeScript?

Because TypeScript can generate JS code like the above, if it's configured to generates modern JS. But if it's configured to generate old ES5 code, then the code it generates looks like this:

```
for (var _i = 0, _a = 7; _i < _a.length; _i++) {
    var f = _a[_i];
    console.log(f.firstName);
}
```

And in this code, `_a.length`is undefined, and since, in JS it's valid to compare a number with undefined, `_i < _a.length` is evaluated to false, and the loop simply is never executed.

Comment: ohhhh ... .I see ... ok that's how it never even goes inside the loop. Cool thanks for explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Typescript isn't magical.

First you need to tell it what type the argument is supposed to be.

Second it's turning your code into Javascript, so once the compile phase is over typescript is gone.

Your code might not do anything as 7 is not an iterable, but it's not going to throw either.

Change it to

```
function printFirstNames(friends: []) { // adding a type here

    console.log("Hello World!");

    for(let f of friends){
        console.log(f.firstName);
    }

}
printFirstNames(7);
```

and Typescript should yell at you.